# need to reset nifi listSFTP processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to clear the cash in my listFTP to reload all the files from my sftp site, it only list new files. 
How can i reset that ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to right-click on the processor and select "View State" from that screen there is a "Clear State" link on the right side.

Comment: Thanks you very much, so simple and yet so hard to find :-)